# Function in html and JS is saying its not declared

Tags: javascript, html

My problem is I am getting the following console error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: videoArrowminus is not defined.

Even though it is defined, I was wondering if anyone could see why its not working because I am stuck.

Here is the JS reference in my html

```
<script src="js/postworkout.js"></script>
```

Here is the onclick:

```
onclick="videoArrowminus()"
```

and this is the function

```
function videoArrowminus(){
    if(playingVid == 1){
            playingVid = 4;
            setvideo('videos/week'+ z +'-1.mp4');
        } else if (playingVid == 2) {
            playingVid = 1;
            setvideo('videos/week'+ z +'-2.mp4');
        } else if (playingVid == 3) {
            playingVid = 2;
            setvideo('videos/week'+ z +'-3.mp4');
        } else if (playingVid == 4) {
            playingVid = 3;
            setvideo('videos/week'+ z +'-4.mp4');
        }
}
```

Comment: The error message says `videoArrowplus` but the code says `videoArrowminus` - which is it?  Please post code and an error message that match.

Comment: `videoArrowplus` != `videoArrowminus`

Comment: before executing 'onclick="videoArrowminus()"' try to defined videoArrowminus() function.

Comment: Eg: first defined videoArrowminus() then call onclick="videoArrowminus()".

Comment: If you are calling the function before the script is loaded, it won't be declared yet. Provide the context of what is actually triggering the error (point in another script, html event trigger, etc) and when. Also, confirm via browser console that the function is declared, assuming it is in the global scope (which is most likely is).

Comment: Basically, there is an arrow that when I press is meant to cycle the videos. So the onclick is on an arrow image.

Comment: Did you call the function after the window load event has finished?

Comment: No, the function only gets called when that arrow is pressed

Comment: And where did you included the js file? At the top or at the bottom of the page? I have a filling the js file is not loaded at the moment when you are calling the method.

Comment: Its the top of the page, it comes just after some of the other script files that are needed and my CSS File

Comment: please post your html. at least the element that triggering that event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really know why it's not working, but maybe you should try include the method invocation inside the javascript file (on window load) something in following way:

```
function videoArrowminus(){
    if(playingVid == 1){
            playingVid = 4;
            setvideo('videos/week'+ z +'-1.mp4');
        } else if (playingVid == 2) {
            playingVid = 1;
            setvideo('videos/week'+ z +'-2.mp4');
        } else if (playingVid == 3) {
            playingVid = 2;
            setvideo('videos/week'+ z +'-3.mp4');
        } else if (playingVid == 4) {
            playingVid = 3;
            setvideo('videos/week'+ z +'-4.mp4');
        }
}

eventListener(window, 'load', function() {
   var element = document.getElementById('someId'); // give some real name
   eventListener(element, 'click', function() {
        videoArrowminus();
   });
});

function eventListener(element, eventName, fn) {
    if (element.addEventListener)
        element.addEventListener(eventName, fn, false);
    else if (element.attachEvent)
        element.attachEvent('on' + eventName, fn);
}
```